# Recursive Nested Arrays - Applying query to multiple array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "date1": "date1",
      "date2": "date2",
      "childArray": [
        {
          "date1": "date1",
          "date2": "date2",
          "childArray": [
            {
              "date1": "date1",
              "date2": "date2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have document that is of the format above - I need to be able to query give a date and fetch all recursively here if the date falls between date1 and date2.

Could use a bit of help -- I've looked into aggregation and a way of potentially flattening this structure out via the aggregation and then applying the query but I haven't gotten anywhere with it.

This is a sample -- the childArray can be any number of layers deep, so need something recursive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `find` and `$or`:

```
var date = ISODate("2020-08-12T23:45:00Z")
db.collection.find({
    $or: [
          {array: { $elemMatch:{
                date1: {$lte: date},
                date2: {$gte: date}
          }}},
          {"array.childArray": { $elemMatch:{
                date1: {$lte: date},
                date2: {$gte: date}
          }}},
          {"array.childArray.childArray": { $elemMatch:{
                date1: {$lte: date},
                date2: {$gte: date}
          }}}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks Joe - updating my question -- it should state that I don't actually know how deep this childArray nesting can go, so I need some sort of recursive query.

Comment: The mongo query language doesn't do looping, branching, or recursion.   A BSON object is limited to 16MB, so there is an upper limit on the possible nesting in the document.  You could programmatically create an `$or` array like this that is thousands deep and query with that.

Comment: Another option I was thinking was that --- could we somehow flatten that array by using map or something --- then query that flattened array.. so take the children and children of children and move them into a single flat array, again that could be done programatically

Comment: There would need to be a match in the fields of each array for graphLookup.  Neither the mongo query language or aggregation have an operator to recursively flatten and array.  You could use `$unwind` repeatedly, but your query would still only handle up to a  specific depth.